# Spark connects from VSCode but doesn't connect from Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, databricks

I have installed databricks-connect and I was able to connect to the clusters and launch some jobs from VSCode.

I saw that it's possible to launch databricks-connect in Jupyter notebook, so from the same terminal of my code in VScode, I have launched Jupyter Notebook in the same environment, but Spark didn't love the idea,

**Here are some snapshots for the problem:**

**This one from VSCode Notebooks (it works also in .py ):**
[image]

**This one from Jupyter Notebook:**
[image]

I have tried findspark, and in our case it's not the solution since I am using Databricks Connect,

I see it more that Spark is not pointing to the same context,

and I repeat, I have launch the notebook from the terminal of the same environment, so logically I have all the env variables the same